# I want to deep link to a screen in Unity app on IOS from Firebase Push Notification

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Unity app, and Firebase integrated. I send push notifications from my api (Laravel) using Firebase, and right now I have it on click opening with a click action using an intent filter for Android. But I am not sure how to do this for ios.

```
$message = new FcmMessage();
$message->content([
    'title'        => 'New Notification!',
    'body'         => 'Username has challenged you.',
    'sound'        => '', // Optional
    'icon'         => '@mipmap/notification_icon', 
    'click_action' => 'OPEN_APP' 
])->priority(FcmMessage::PRIORITY_HIGH); 
return $message;
```